# Morphism of a linear system contracting curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex surface and $L$ a line bundle such that the linear system $|L|$ has no basepoints and $h^0(X,L)>0$. Denote by $\phi:X\rightarrow\Bbb{P}(H^0(X,L)^\vee)$ the morphism associated to $L$.

Let $C$ be a curve on $X$ such that $C.L=0$. Does this imply that $\phi$ contracts $C$ to a point? Conversely, any 1-dimensional fiber will be of this kind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is right.

The morphism $\phi$ has the property that $L=\phi^* O(1)$. So the projection formula tells us that for any curve or more generally effective 1-cycle $C$ on $X$ we have

$$ L \cdot C = O(1) \cdot \phi_*(C) $$

Since $O(1)$ is ample on $\mathbb P$, we get that $L \cdot C = 0$ if and only if $C$ is contracted by $\phi$.

Comment: Very ingenious (unsurprisingly from you...) .

Comment: Thank you, @GeorgesElencwajg. Sadly, the downvoter didn't agree...